# mvn release:perform automatically specify scm tag that includes release version

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I would like to setup my maven release to run in batch mode, but I'm not a fan of the default scm tag `${artifactId}-${releaseVersion}`.  Instead, I'd like to simply tag it with `${releaseVersion}`; however, I'm unclear if such a property exists (ie. without the -SNAPSHOT suffix).

I'd like the configuration to resemble the code below.  Is such a default tagging possible with the maven-release-plugin?

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <tag>${releaseVersion}</tag>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Part of the reason for running in batch mode is to perform automated releases.  So this has to happen without any interaction.

Comment: This is very similar to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466714/how-to-customise-the-tag-format-of-the-maven-release-plugin

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this:

```
<configuration>
     <tag>${project.version}</tag>
</configuration>
```

Comment: When I run this, at least with a mvn release:prepare -DdryRun=true, I get the scm tag 0.2-SNAPSHOT(ie. with -SNAPSHOT).  I'm looking for an easy way to get the version number without SNAPSHOT.

Comment: strange, isn't the release supposed to be a normal version and not a napshot --> Change the version in the POMs from x-SNAPSHOT to a new version

Comment: Change the version in the POMs from x-SNAPSHOT to a new version --> taken from the documentation

Comment: When running the release:prepare in batch mode the maven-release-plugin manages updating all the pom files (ie. 0.2-SNAPSHOT becomes 0.2).  So I can't change the pom files.  I'm just trying to find out if there is a property I can use to determine the target release version; the maven-release-plugin documentation suggest one exists I'm just hopeful.

Comment: sorry, i don't mean you should change the pom. 'Change the version in the POMs from x-SNAPSHOT to a new version '. you shouldn't do this yourselves, the release plug-in does this for you. and indeed, my proposed solution doesn't work.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a way to do this. there's no property you could use for this. also, see the second answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782301/maven-release-via-hudson

Comment: :( - See related JIRA issue - 
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-259 and
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-159

Comment: @user294059 Please un-mark this as the answer so the question is known to be unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this to work when using Hudson to do my release.  I noted that Hudson (with the Maven Release Plugin) is initiating the command with a property like -Dproject.rel.com.example:my-artifact-id=1.0.1.  Using the following plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <tag>REL-${project.rel.com.example:my-artifact-id}</tag>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Resulted in the tag being REL-1.0.1

I'm new to the release plugin but I would assume something similar would work from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the properties for:

releaseVersion -- What version you want it to be released as (1.0)
developmentVersion -- The next version (2.0-SNAPSHOT)
tag -- The name of the tag

a 1.0-SNAPSHOT implies a 1.0 release version, but doesn't set it.  You can set that property in your POM file as a regular property.