# How to customise the tag format of the Maven release plugin?

Tags: maven, release, default, tagging, maven-release-plugin

In our SVN repo, we store tags like this:

```
trunk
    project_a
    project_b
branches
    project_a
        branch_x
        branch_y
    project_b
tags
    project_a
        1.0
        1.1
    project_b
        1.0
```

When I run the Maven release plugin's "[prepare](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html)" goal on project A, by default it creates the tag as "tags/project_a-x.x", which does not match my tag naming scheme above. I am thus depending upon whoever does the release (i.e. a fallible human) to spot this and change the tag to "tags/project_a/x.x". How can I tell the release plugin to use the correct format by default?

The "prepare" goal has a "[tag](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#tag)" configuration option that claims to do this, but if I set it as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <tag>${project.artifactId}/${project.version}</tag>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

... then the created tag is "tags/project_a/x.x-SNAPSHOT", i.e. it uses the pre-release version number instead of the release version number. Hardcoding the tag name into the POM seems wrong too.

How can I ensure that the tag is correct by default?

Comment: See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466714/how-to-customise-the-tag-format-of-the-maven-release-plugin#comment21031508_13886493) below. This behaviour is broken again in v2.4. In fact, v2.1 of the release plugin is the only one currently working properly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The release plugin now supports the `tagNameFormat` [configuration option](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#tagNameFormat), which defaults to `@{project.artifactId}-@{project.version}`. In your case, you could do something like:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <tagNameFormat>@{project.artifactId}/@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note that, in order to ensure that the interpolation occurs during release, you must use `@{...}` to reference the properties rather than `${...}`.

Comment: Please note that **v2.1** is the latest version in which this behaviour works correctly. Since that release, the code base is broken and the `-SNAPSHOT` version is used. See [this bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-695) for further info.

Comment: Note the at-sign in @{project.version} is important. The similar looking ${project.version} just gets the version from the pom.xml. I don't the significance of $ and @?

Comment: I just used **v2.5.3** and a it correctly tagged using just the project version using a configuration of: `<tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is not possible until one of these bugs is fixed:

- [MRELEASE-150](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-150): Can't add prefix to tags without affecting version *(not scheduled)*
- [MRELEASE-159](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-159): Support a pattern to generate the release tag *(scheduled for 2.2)*
- [MRELEASE-259](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-259): Provide a configuration settings for default tag/label to use when releasing *(not scheduled)*

Comment: MRELEASE-159 has been marked as fixed in 2.2, and the other two tickets are marked as duplicates of it. I no longer use SVN, but I've changed the accepted answer to Lyle's, which documents the new tagNameFormat option.

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing in the releaseVersion, you can do this:

```xml
<tag>${project.artifactId}/${releaseVersion}</tag>
```